# Convert ASM to Delphi 7

Tags: delphi, assembly, reverse-engineering

```
Unit1.TForm1.Button1Click
    push  0
    push  ebx
    mov   ebx, eax
    ...
    lea   eax,[ebp-4]
    mov   edx,44EB18;`test`
    call  LStrLAsg
    mov   edx,dword ptr [ebp-4]
    mov   eax,dword ptr [ebx+2FC];TForm1.Label1:TLabel
    call  TControl.SetText
    ...
```

But the Delphi code is simple:

```
str := 'test';
Label1.Caption := str;
```

But I wanna use this `asm ... end;` tag for this.
as following code. But I can't compile this code.

```
asm
  lea         eax,[ebp-4]
  mov         edx, 'test'
  call        @LStrLAsg
  mov         edx,dword ptr [ebp-4]
  mov         eax, TForm1.Label1; TForm1.Label1:TLabel
  call        TControl.SetText
end;
```

Comment: What is your question? If you have a syntax error, please report it. Further, it's pointless to use asm for this code. Why would you do that?

Comment: i lost source file. so i wanna rewritten source code from asm. and then error is LSTRLAsg is not identify.

Comment: You aren't going to succeed in doing this. If you want to disassemble a program, use a disassembler. Websearch will lead you to Delphi disassemblers.

Comment: Can I use LStrLAsg in asm part in delphi project?

Comment: What's wrong with `Label1.Caption := 'test';`? Seems to me that you aren't telling us the entire story. You aren't going to disassemble an large program by hand, use a disassembler for that. If you only want to work on a couple of routines, translate them to Pascal.

Comment: @JongJong: _LStrAsg is a function in System that is hidden for normal use. Only the compiler can access it (and then you'll see it in a disassembly as @LstrAsg -- @ is not used for normal functions). I don't think you can access it at all, but you could try `call System.@LstrAsg`. It doesn't make sense to try to do this though. You won't be able to access TForm1.Label1 like that either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several problems with your code, and the biggest one is that `TControl.SetText` is private. Your code won't assemble, no matter what you try. You will have to use plain Pascal.

But I'll address the other problems anyway, FYI.

**TL;DR**

Let's start at the beginning:

```
lea eax,[ebp-$04]
```

That tries to take the address of a local variable. You don't know where on the stack this will actually be, so rather use the name. This means you must declare local variables and constants like:

```
const
  C: string = 'test'; // In D7, string is AnsiString
var
  X: string;
asm
  lea eax,X
  mov edx,C
```

The assembler will add code to set up the stack frame requried for that.

**But this way, you are discarding eax, which contains the self pointer.** You will have to save this first, either in a local variable or by pushing it on the stack:

```
var
  LSelf: Pointer;
asm
  mov LSelf,eax
```

Later on, you can then use it, e.g. to access the form.

Then you try to access a hidden System function, `_LStrAsg`. This is not meant to be used by user code. The compiler has special knowledge about such functions in *System.pas*. Perhaps it is accessible as

```
call System.@LStrAsg
```

But don't bet on it.

Then you try to access `TForm1.Label1`. That is not possible like that in assembler either. You could try something like (untested):

```
mov eax,LSelf
mov eax,[eax].TForm1.Label1
```

but I am not sure if that works in D7.

So now we have:

```
const
  C: string = 'test'; // In D7, this is an AnsiString, hence _LStrAsg

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  S: string;
  LSelf: Pointer;
asm
    mov LSelf,eax           // save self pointer
    lea eax,S               // S := C;
    mov edx,C
    call System.@LStrAsg
    mov eax,LSelf           // Self.Label1.Caption := S;
    mov eax,[eax].TForm1.Label1
    mov edx,S
    call TControl.SetText
end;
```

**But that doesn't compile. The biggest problem is that `TControl.SetText` 
is *private*. You won't be able to access it. I tried several tricks, but to no avail. All of them result in `Undeclared identifier: 'SetText'`.**

So what is left is to do it without assembler:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Label1.Caption := 'test';
end;
```

Comment: FWIW, in the newest Delphis, (including the free Delphi 10.2 Community Edition), you could use one of the tricks (using class helpers) in [my blog post about accessing private methods](http://rvelthuis.blogspot.com/2018/01/accessing-private-methods-of-another.html).